# Why does Southeast Asia have a resistance towards allowing same-sex marriages?

Tags: international, same-sex-marriage, southeast-asia, asia

> BANGKOK (AP) — Lawmakers in Thailand’s lower house of Parliament
> overwhelmingly approved a marriage equality bill on Wednesday that
> would make the country the first in Southeast Asia to legalize equal
> rights for marriage partners of any gender.
>
> The bill passed its final reading with the approval of 400 of the 415
> members of the House of Representatives in attendance, with 10 voting
> against it, two abstaining and three not voting.
>
> Thailand has a reputation for acceptance and inclusivity but has
> struggled for decades to pass a marriage equality law. Thai society
> largely holds conservative values, and members of the LGBTQ+ community
> say they face discrimination in everyday life. The government and
> state agencies are also historically conservative, and advocates for
> gender equality have had a hard time pushing lawmakers and civil
> servants to accept change.
>
> The bill now goes to the Senate, which rarely rejects any legislation
> that passes the lower house, and then to the king for royal
> endorsement. This would make Thailand the first country or region in
> Southeast Asia to pass such a law and the third in Asia, after Taiwan
> and Nepal.

https://apnews.com/article/thailand-marriage-same-sex-equality-law-9a2f9da6b5b36a1cf70dee5caec70e23

Why does Southeast Asia have a resistance towards allowing same-sex marriages? I learned today that Thailand just became the first country to approve marriage equality in the whole region of Southeast Asia. Is there a reason why Southeast Asia is resistant towards the idea of legalizing same-sex marriage?

Comment: It's important to take into account that not every society is at the same point in how they interact with minorities or traditionally under-empowered peoples.  In 1939, an American or Canadian might, with some justification, ask themselves what was wrong with a country like [France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_women%27s_suffrage), that did not let women vote.  And the answer would mostly be... they haven't done it yet and they are not us.  Same-sex marriage is a [**very recent (2001)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-sex_marriage) development in the West.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 11 countries in [Southeast Asia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southeast_Asia) proper (incl. Thailand). Of these:

- 3 are Muslim-majority: Indonesia, Malaysia, and Brunei.
- 3 are Communist-like (China-style authoritarian): Cambodia, Vietnam, Laos.
- Myanmar is run by a military dictatorship. (Yeah, Thailand had some of that too, but the current move comes in one of their more liberal phases, with the PTP leading the government.)

There's not much reason to expect those types of countries to legalize same-sex marriage. (Not even Kosovo or Bosnia-Herzegovina do.)

So that leaves the Philippines, Singapore, and East Timor as somewhat less unlikely to make such a move. But East Timor and the Philippines are Catholic dominated, which probably plays a role in them not rushing to this. (E.g. Italy still doesn't, but recognizes same-sex civil unions.) In a 2022 [poll](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-08-12/same-sex-union-bill-filed-in-predominantly-catholic-philippines), around 60% of Filipinos are opposed to even same-sex civil unions. Singapore is also somewhat authoritarian and culturally [conservative](https://www.straitstimes.com/singapore/community/singapore-still-conservative-on-moral-sexuality-issues-but-more-liberal-since). (Interestingly, based on a survey in that last link Muslims are much more opposed [75%] to homosexuality than Catholics are [18%], in Singapore.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what there is to say except:

- Legalizing same-sex marriage is a [liberal concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberalism).
- Southeast Asia is traditionally [conservative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservatism) ([example](https://www.straitstimes.com/singapore/community/singapore-still-conservative-on-moral-sexuality-issues-but-more-liberal-since), see also [Asian values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_values)).

Conservative countries don't implement liberal policies.